# ffmpeg mp4 file is not valid

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

I was looking for answer on Internet but, didn't find any...

Got 3 movies, all made by ffmpeg from separate frames in png files with command:

`ffmpeg -r 100 -qscale 2 -i input/%06d.png output/movie.mp4`

Two of them work perfectly... Windows Media Player and all others see it as correct format..., but one of them not. Only VLC can play it, all other players say that it is unknown format. It probably has something to do with size of images. Would like to know what are the criteria... what size should it have... why one is working and other is not...

Sizes are:

1. 1600x1570 - works fine
2. 1880x616 - works fine
3. 1891x725 - doesn't work...

This is really weird, because fullhd has width of `1920`, so all above are lower...

All images are made by PHP with gdlib, all saved the same method... it is not the problem of count, because no matter if I get only first 100 frames, or whole movie, it still doesn't work... only the last one. Any ideas what could possibly be wrong?

Complete FFMPEG output (for 200 frames):

```
FFmpeg version SVN-r0.5.10-4:0.5.10-1, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
  configuration: --extra-version=4:0.5.10-1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libdirac --enable-libgsm --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --disable-stripping --disable-vhook --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libfaad --enable-libdc1394 --enable-shared --disable-static
  libavutil     49.15. 0 / 49.15. 0
  libavcodec    52.20. 1 / 52.20. 1
  libavformat   52.31. 0 / 52.31. 0
  libavdevice   52. 1. 0 / 52. 1. 0
  libavfilter    0. 4. 0 /  0. 4. 0
  libswscale     0. 7. 1 /  0. 7. 1
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
  built on Feb 16 2013 09:22:58, gcc: 4.4.5
Input #0, image2, from 'input/%06d.png':
  Duration: 00:00:02.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: png, rgb24, 1891x725, 100 tbr, 100 tbn, 100 tbc
Output #0, mp4, to 'output/movie.mp4':
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 1891x725, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 100 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
Press [q] to stop encoding
frame=  201 fps= 14 q=2.0 Lsize=   10032kB time=2.01 bitrate=40886.7kbits/s
video:10030kB audio:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.023690%
```

PS. Even after converting in different application to FullHD (added black bars), it still doesn't work.

Comment: Please include the complete `ffmpeg` console output.

Comment: LordNeckbeard: Added to question.

Comment: probably your players can't handle the odd width...

Comment: after changing width to same as in 2nd one (1880), still doesn't work... so my question is why some dimentions are working and some are not...? and what dimentions work...

Comment: `FFmpeg version SVN-r0.5.10` is absolutely ancient. Do yourself a favor and try a [recent build of `ffmpeg`](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds).

Comment: I can't... has to be this build... anyway making black border around frames so input would be FullHD and then encoding it, helped. Still now answer for question why `1880x616` works and `1891x725` does not.